# Server showing php script as it is without executing

Tags: php, apache

I have made a subdomain and uploaded php script on that. but php code is shown there included file are also not shown on page.

In description, i have made a sub domain jobs.example.com. All project done in php on locally when is uploaded it to the srever (in the root flder of jobs.example.com). only html css and jquery is running php code is shown there as it is. How may i handle this plese help me.

Comment: Are you sure your server supports php? Is php support turned on for the directory you have the php file in? Do you have the correct `<?php ?>` tags around the code? If you post the details of which webserver (and version) you are using, as well as a small example code file which doesn't work, then it'll mean people are much more able to help you.

Comment: It is sure server fully support php. the main domain is running php correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is:  may be you might need to set up your subdomain folder to run php files.

You might need to setup mime type for .php

```
# Add this line inside the <IfModule mod_mime.c> conditional brace
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Referenced from : http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache1.php